# How to select Collective data through SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
SELECT COUNT(a.running_ID)
       ,a.operation_name
       ,a.return_Code
    FROM log_master_2may_q9 a
       ,log_detail_2may_q9 b
    WHERE a.execution_id = b.execution_id
        AND b.type = 'MSISDN'
        AND operation_name IN ( 'manageProfile', 'getPayment' )
    GROUP BY a.return_Code
       ,a.operation_name;
```

Here what happening is I am getting data from with Multiples Return Code like '101', '102', '902' which is for Failure and Return code '100' and 'S' for success.

With every return_Code I am getting some count.

Now what I want is a collective data found for Failures code and same for success code.

I tried using Concat command for above query but getting error.

Can anyone please help here ?

Additional Info :

Data is coming from multiple tables here.

Output coming is like this:

Count(A.running_ID) operation_name  record_code
765                getPayment         102
14                 ManageProfile      102
10                 getPayment         902
661                ManageProfile      S
262                ManageProfile      100
11737              getPayment         100
20                 getPayment         101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  Sum(case When a.return_Code = '101' then 1 end) Code101Total,
  Sum(case When a.return_Code = '102' then 1 end) Code102Total,
  Sum(case When a.return_Code = '902' then 1 end) Code902Total,
  Sum(case When a.return_Code = '100' then 1 end) Code100Total,
  Sum(case When a.return_Code = '100' then 1 end) Code100Total,
  Sum(case When a.return_Code In ('101', '102', '902') then 1 end) Fails,
  Sum(case When a.return_Code = '100' then 1 end) SuccessesTotal
FROM log_master_2may_q9 a
   join log_detail_2may_q9 b
      on b.execution_id = a.execution_id
WHERE b.type = 'MSISDN'
    AND operation_name IN ( 'manageProfile', 'getPayment' )
GROUP BY a.return_Code
```

Comment: Its not giving the desired result . As with this I am just getting additional columns with error code name but what is desired is if : for operation name "manageprofile" if I getting error code "902" and seeing 20 as count then for "101" code seeing count as 780 and for "102" its 56 then it should show only one column as fails in which sum of the above three should come as 856.

Comment: Made some modifications to the query you provided according to my need and now its working for me. Thanks Charles....